# Rails console limits text output. How do I get to see it all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb, rails-console

It seems like the Rails console limits its character output to about 880 characters.
How do I remove this limitation?

Printing large objects, or text fields from the database, gives output like this:

```
=> #<User id: ....
system_password: ni
```

(`...` inserted for brevity. The output contains lots and lots of text.)

You can see that the output is truncated / capped/ limited, so that nothing after 'ni' is displayed (should have been atleast an 'l', for 'nil').

This is so annoying. It doesn't allow me to fully inspect the string / text fields in the DB that contain a lot of text.

I presume it must be a setting somewhere, but I can't seem find it.

How do I remove this limitation, so I can see all of the text output?

Comment: I think it might have something to do with UTF-8 characters in the output..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think irb or the Rails console is the problem.  This doesn't truncate from either plain irb or `rails c`:

```
(1..100000).reduce(''){|a,i| a << i.to_s}
```

The Rails console output is coming from the `inspect` method, so it's probably ActiveRecord that is doing the truncation ([code here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/77b4edce1544f105cc7764249becc1e998b88fc2/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L636)).  You should be able to override the `inspect` method in your User model if you want custom output.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to recommend [pry](http://pry.github.com/), which supports Rails well and you can view details of ActiveRecord instances with it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and got past it by requesting just the one field I needed.  For example, saying `Vote.find(38)` yielded text with a `...`, but when I went straight to `Vote.find(38).description` it had the unshortened version.